# Using firewall-cmd to open up a port for INPUT only

Tags: linux, port, centos-7

I'm using firewall-cmd on centos7 to open up a port. But, I want to open up the port for INPUT only. I currently have this, but it, presumbably, opens it for INPUT and OUTPUT.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8443/tcp --permanent
```

In centos6, I could do this using iptables like this, but I'm not sure what the analog to this is with firewall-cmd

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes from searching over the internet a bit, not own knowledge and was not tested.

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT`

[Source](https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-firewalld/)

Comment: I was able to use this and it worked. I had to add a --permanent flag to persist the change, as noted in your source link.